# PostGis Dump file to SpatialLite without going through PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, sqlite

I received a large (2Gb) postgis dump file that I'd like to work with. But I don't want to deal with a PostgreSQL installation so I though about using SpatialLite. Is it possible to restore a pg_dump file straight into Sqlite?